# I am trying to access a value from an array at a given index but I keep getting undefined

Tags: reactjs

with this I can access the level above but when I go to access a specific year I get undefined

```
render() {
    console.log('mine', this.state.list)
    return (
      <div>
        <select name="country" type="select-multiple" multiple={true} value={this.state.list} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selected: e.target.value })}>

          {this.state.list.map((e, key) => {
            return <option key={key} value={JSON.stringify(e.data.life_expectancy_years)}>{e.name}</option>
          })}
        </select>
        <p> {this.state.selected}
        </p>

      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

the above code works but if I put in

```
value={JSON.stringify(e.data.life_expectancy_years[2000])}
```

it comes up with undefined

my data looks like

```
country{data:{life_expectancy_years: {1800: "28.2", 2000: "28.2"}}}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT

Unfortunately I didn't get the structure quite right so here goes

```
country{name{}:data{life_expectancy_years:{1800: "28.2", 2000: "28.2"}}}
```

I think that's right my apologies

or directly from console '

100: {_id: {…}, name: "Madagascar", data: {…}}

Comment: what do you mean by `the above code works`? because, you set a select value to list then serialize some value to options which make little sense to me at the first glance

Comment: try with `e.data.life_expectancy_years['2000']`

Comment: thanks. Same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2000' of undefined

Comment: @Rostyslav sorry I should have been more clear. The above code prints out all the values but when I try to get a specific one it fails

Comment: @Lucky1 it is obvious that it prints all values. The question is what values, because there is no `name` property in your data model `country{data:{life_expectancy_years: {1800: "28.2", 2000: "28.2"}}}`

Comment: ahh sorry I see what you mean. It the data actually looks like, country:name:data:life...years[1800 : etc

Comment: @Lucky1 could you please edit your question and paste a JSON with clear structure? because it is still unclear to me from your comment

Comment: are you sure you not having `life_expectancy_years` under `country` and not `data` ?

Comment: no its definitly under data `e.data` gives me `life_expectancy_years`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved it. I should have shown you my initial state because that was the issue.

I had

```
    this.state = { 'list': [{ name: 'Please select a country', data: {} }] }
```

when I should of had

```
    this.state = { 'list': [{ name: 'Please select a country', data: {life_expectancy_years:{}} }] }
```

I was assuming that the data portion would just follow my existing json but was wrong